# Perforce: How can I see a changelist from only a set of files in a directory with p4 commands?

Tags: perforce, changelist

I have a folder, named for e.g. 'alphabet', where it contains the files: 'a','b','c' and 'z'.

I want to have a report on the last change from time to time in this folder. But I want to ignore the changes on the file 'z'.

If I do p4 changes //Path/... I don't want to catch the changes made on the file 'z'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Unix `sort` utility you can do it like this:

```
p4 changes //depot/alphabet/a //depot/alphabet/b //depot/alphabet/c | sort -u
```

Another option would be to set up your client view to exclude this file:

```
View:
    //depot/... //myclient/...
    -//depot/alphabet/z //myclient/alphabet/z
```

and then use the client view in your query:

```
p4 changes //myclient/alphabet/...
```

or just use the local path:

```
cd alphabet
p4 changes ...
```